read and assign a column_type_schedule in readr based on column index
I have many identical structured tab-delimited-files with data.
I want to read column types from 1 file with readr::read_tsv. Extract a schedule with columntypes. Modify the column types for some columns manually in the schedule. Read all other files based on this schedule.
Since these columns have some special characters and duplicates in the names, I thought it would be usefull to use indexes instead of columnnames.
I have tried with chatgpt although I do not succeed to generate code which succeeds in this task.
I can provide my code here which gives errors or can someone provide a simple example?
That would be great. Thanks a lot!
